# Does a computer system (Linux) only have one host name?

Tags: linux, hostname

`hostname` is used to display the system's DNS name, and to display or set its hostname or NIS domain name.

Does a computer system (Linux) only have one host name?

In virtual hosting, several host names can be resolved to different root directories in a web server. If a computer system (Linux) can only have one host name, how is virtual hosting possible?

Thanks.

Comment: DNS A or AAA records point to the same IP address for multiple domains.  The hostname of the machine is not necessarily important.

Comment: (1) Is the output of `hostname` ever used in resolving hostname to IP address? (2) A means IPv4 address, AAAA IPv6. What is AAA?

Comment: mDNS services, such as `avahi` depend on the machine hostname.  In that case, `hostname.local` would resolve to the local IP address of the machine.  I see someone wrote an answer which is an expansion of my first comment... too simultaneous for my browser notifications.

Comment: AAA is a 'A' short typo

Comment: Virtual Host has nothing to do with hostname. It purely depends on web server behavior. The server responses differently to different Host field of HTTP request header. I don't think typical web server would do anything related to DNS or hostname to offer virtual host functionality.

Comment: @炸   " I don't think typical web server would do anything related to DNS or hostname to offer virtual host functionality". without DNS,  how can www.example.com and www.example.net be resolved to the same IP address, if they are virtual hosting on that IP address?

Comment: virtual host is a string send to server, hostname is an alias of server IP. Totally unrelated. See the answer you get

Answer (score 30):

Yes, and no. The are two distinct things called hostnames.

**The "internal" hostname** is basically a string kept by the kernel. This is the one returned by the `hostname` command (or the `gethostname()` call) and it's unique within a system<sup>(*)</sup>.

It's mostly used when a program wants to output some identifier for the system it's running on. E.g. `\h` in Bash's `PS1` expands to the hostname. Similarly, syslog-style logfiles also include the hostname on log entries.

<sup>(* Though as Stephen Kitt comments, [namespaces](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html) can be used to show different hostnames to processes on the same system. That's mostly used for containers, which try to act like they're distinct systems.)</sup>

**Then there's also DNS names** that are used by other systems to look up the IP address of another. There might be more than one DNS name that point to the same IP address, and so the same host.

The internal hostname and the DNS names don't need to be the same. Suppose someone has a webserver they've decided to call `orange`<sup>(*)</sup>, with the IP address `192.0.2.9` . 
It could serve two different domains and the DNS would be set up to have `www.example.org` and `www.example.com` both point to `192.0.2.9`, while the internal hostname of the system might be `orange.example.org` or just `orange`. In that case, the DNS setup would usually also have a [reverse lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) on `192.0.2.9` point back to the name `orange.example.org`, but there's nothing to force that.

<sub>(* because they like to name their servers after fruit. Someone might use `webserver1` or such, but the point is that it doesn't need to be named after one of the actual domains.)</sub>

In addition to that, virtual hosting requires that the browser tell the web server the name of the site it tried to access. Otherwise the server would not know which virtual site the client tried to reach. HTTP has the [`Host` header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43156023/what-is-http-host-header) for that.

---

What muddies the distinction between a DNS name and the internal hostname is the [mDNS protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS)
(implemented e.g. by the [avahi daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_(software))) and other discovery protocols. mDNS makes it possible for hosts to query all other
hosts on the same network for name information, and to make their own hostnames visible on other hosts
without explicitly setting them up in DNS.

Comment: Thanks. (1) "the DNS setup would usually have 192.0.2.9 point back to the name orange.example.org" Doesn't resolving get IP address for a given host name, why the opposite? (2) Is the output of `hostname` ever used in resolving hostname to IP address?

Comment: (2) ... When set up a local wifi network in your home from an ISP using a router and modem, the machines in the network can be identified by the outputs of their `hostname` commands, correct? Does the router act like a DNS to resolve the outputs of `hostname` to private IP addresses in the network?

Comment: @Tim, (2) uhhuh, I'm not sure. There might be (probably are) systems that automatically discover hosts on the same network, but I'm not too familiar with them. (I know Windows does it, but that doesn't help much.) There would need to be an additional protocol there to communicate the hostnames and IP's and to have them show up as DNS names on the other hosts.

Comment: as for (1), there's also reverse lookups that take the IP address and return a name. (For a system with a single name and a single address, you'd want to have both resolve to the other, just for clarity's sake)

Comment: (2) In such a local wifi network, I can use `ssh name@hostname` to access a SSH server on another computer, where `hostname` is the output of command `hostname`. So I guess that the output of `hostname` is automatically used and resolved to private IP address, by some DNS server (on the router)? In that case, output of `hostname` and host name used in DNS are not unrelated, and is that an exception to what you mentioned?

Comment: @Tim yeah, then you have some software that automatically discovers the other hosts and makes their names available. But like I said, I'm not really familiar with those, so there's not much I can say. The internal hostname and the DNS name would still be technically distinct, you'd just have something that syncs one from the other.

Comment: I thought the output of `hostname` is used in hostname resolving on the internet until your reply. If it is not used for that purpose, what purpose is it used for?

Comment: Kernel hostname don't have to be unique. When another machine try to access machineA by hostname, it only needs to resolve hostname to machineA's IP, by whatever method. I don't think kernel itself would do DNS request or response, it's purely a userspace behavior

Comment: @Tim, it's the value that e.g. a shell would use if it shows the hostname in the prompt. And other stuff like that. Mostly just an identifier that's always there.

Comment: Kernel hostname is a almost legacy functionality, it stores one string in the kernel, letting you read or change it. And that's it, pretty much useless for complex network DNS needs.

Comment: Small networks may be using [`mDNS`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS). For better or worse, it lets system owners choose their own hostnames, accessible by other systems on the local network, without the need to register with a DNS server.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick ... most current distros use [avahi](https://avahi.org/) in the default installation.

Comment: In many home networks, the local router acts as a DNS resolver. Hosts send their hostname when they request an address using DHCP, and the router remembers that name and resolves it for all hosts on the network. As Mark and RubberStamp mention, there’s also Bonjour (implemented in Avahi) which allows for service discovery on the LAN (printers in particular). Note too that hosts can have multiple IP addresses, and hostnames are now namespaced so processes can see different hostnames on the same host.

Comment: It's referred to in doco as variously the _dynamic hostname_ ([`set-dynamic-hostname`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/set-dynamic-hostname.xml)), the _transient hostname_ ([`hostnamectl`](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/hostnamectl.html)), or the _node name_ ([`uname()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/uname.2.html)).

Comment: _"The 'internal' hostname (for lack of a better phrase)"_ - Perhaps "canonical hostname"?

Comment: @marcelm, I meant the technical distinction between the two, canonical doesn't really communicate that. Plus it's sometimes used in reference to an FQDN, and is the C in CNAME, so it really hints too much at DNS. I should have probably just used "kernel hostname". (But of course it might be possible that there's some weird OS somewhere that keeps the hostname only in userspace, with the kernel having no knowledge of it... Luckily this was tagged with Linux, which keeps it in the kernel.)

Answer (score 8):

> Does a computer system (Linux) only have one host name?

No.

[I'll completely ignore that anybody may give your host any name they like by having a DNS record pointing to its address, or that you can have more than one alias for it in `/etc/hosts`, or any philosophical considerations about what a [name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_and_Necessity) really is]

On a linux system, the hostname is simply a per-process resource (the "UTS namespace") that is inherited by its children by default, but could be disjoined from with `unshare(2)` or `clone(2)` by using the `CLONE_NEWUTS` flag. You should look into the `namespaces(7)` manpage.

Just like pids, port numbers, mount points, etc the hostname is no longer a global identifier, and it could be virtualized just the same as the address space (virtual memory) or the file descriptor table of a process.

> In virtual hosting, several host names can be resolved to different root directories in a web server. If a computer system (Linux) can only have one host name, how is virtual hosting possible?

Virtual hosting is something completely different, and it's usually done by configuring a wildcard DNS record (eg. `*.foo.com` => `13.13.13.13`) with a web server running on `13.13.13.13` and serving different directories / resources based on value of the http `Host:` header[1] (which is highly configurable; most web servers are able to serve different resources based on **any** http header, not just `Host:`). In all this, the OS of the system the web server is running on plays no part.

[1] or on the value of the [server name indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) in case of https, which allows the same webserver to use different certificates for different virtual hosts.

Comment: I have to disagree with you on this. For virtual hosting, we generally have a specific set of cname records pointing to the single host. We do not use a wildcard DNS record as we have many systems within the domain needing virtual hosts. Excluding UTS namespaces (how widely used is this anyway?), you have hostnamectl reporting a single hostname for a given server. DNS and hostnamectl are orthogonal and have little to do with each other.

Comment: @DougO'Neal What are you disagreeing with? That wildcard DNS records are used in the way I describe it? They're wildly used like that (sorry for the pun), whether you like it or not.   That the uts info is virtualized per-process in linux? That's simply the way it is. As to the idea that namespaces are only used / to be used by canned containerization/virtualization solutions (as suggested in the other answer), sorry but that is "only girls play with dolls" or "manual transmissions are only used in heavy trucks" quality ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You usually set a single hostname in `/etc/hostname`. And, you set many domain names in `/etc/hosts`.

UTS namespaces allow a single system to appear to have different host and domain names to different processes. For more info see [Linux namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_namespaces). So, it is absolutely possible to have multiple hostnames  and domain names for the same system. E.g., docker container inside the same host has different hostname  than host system.